# How does Spring @Configuration cache references to beans

Tags: java, spring

How does Spring prevent a second call to bar() when using Java based configurations?

I'm wondering compile time annotation processing or by proxying the method?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public Foo foo() {
      return new Foo(bar());
  }

  @Bean
  public Foo foo2() {
      return new Foo(bar());
  }

  @Bean
  public Bar bar() {
      return new Bar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you created your context a little something like

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

Because of `@Configuration`, Spring will create a bean of type `AppConfig` and proxy it because it has `@Bean` methods. You should check out `ConfigurationClassEnhancer` for [implementation details.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java)

These methods aren't called on the object directly. Obviously they can't since they aren't known at compile time. They are called through reflection on the proxy.

So when you have

```
@Bean
public CustomBean foo() {
    return new CustomBean(bar());
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
@Bean
public CustomBean foo() {
    return new CustomBean(this.bar());
}
```

the `this` is referring to a proxy which caches the result of the method invocation and returns it immediately if it's called it before.

Comment: Ah, the good ol' mysterious Spring automagic. Why not just use parameter injection?

Comment: @leo-the-manic Do you mean through `@Autowired` annotated methods? Sometimes you don't have a choice. `CustomBean` might be a 3rd party class that doesn't expose any other initialization method.

Comment: I suppose my comment is more geared towards Spring itself rather than your answer. Looking at the code from a strictly Java point of view it DOES look like it'll create two different instances. I dislike that Spring chose to automagically proxy/cache the methods for you rather than do something that's more apparent and understandable.

Comment: I should probably also mention I'm a Spring newcomer, trying to wrap my head around all the different parts

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not "prevent" a call to `bar()`.
Instead, at startup, spring generates a list of `@Bean` marked methods then calls each method one time.
If you want, you can call `bar()` a hundred times.
Spring, however; will only call it one time.